# Здравствуйте, необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии открывалось соответствующее уведомление

Tags: javascript

Разбираюсь с js. Необходимо сделать, чтобы при клике на именно этот элемент открывалась соответствующее именно ему сообщение(а не все разом), при условии что все сообщения и кнопки одинаковы.

Вот код js, html и css

js:

```
const cardNotification = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__notification')
const cardBasket = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__basket')

    cardBasket.forEach( elem => {
        elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cardNotification.forEach((items) => {
                items.classList.toggle('active')
            })
        })
    })
```

html:

```
                <div class="col-3 catalog__card card-catalog">
                    <div class="catalog__notification">Добавить в корзину</div>
                    <div class="catalog__basket"></div>

                    <img class="catalog__img" src="./img/bike.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="catalog__price">
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
                        <p class="catalog-price">100$</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 catalog__card card-catalog">
                    <div class="catalog__notification">Добавить в корзину</div>
                    <div class="catalog__basket"></div>

                    <img class="catalog__img"   src="./img/bike.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="catalog__price">
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
                        <p class="catalog-price">1000$</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

css:

```
.catalog__basket {
    background-image: url(/img/backet.png);
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.catalog__notification {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: -50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cardBasket = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__basket');
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.close-notification');
const cardNotification = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__notification');

cardBasket.forEach((basket, index) => {
    basket.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardNotification[index].style.display = 'block';
    });

    closeButtons[index].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardNotification[index].style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

```css
.catalog__basket {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}

.catalog__notification {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    background: white;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    padding: 10px;
}

.card-catalog {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.catalog__img {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-3 {
    max-width: 300px;
}

.catalog__notification {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.close-notification {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: tomato;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 catalog__card card-catalog">
    <div class="catalog__basket"><b>Добавить в корзину</b></div>
    <div class="catalog__notification">
        <p>Сообщение для товара 1</p>
        <button class="close-notification">Закрыть</button>
    </div>
    <img class="catalog__img" src="http://surl.li/mdsxm" alt="img">
    <div class="catalog__price">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p class="catalog-price">100$</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-3 catalog__card card-catalog">
    <div class="catalog__basket"><b>Добавить в корзину</b></div>
    <div class="catalog__notification">
        <p>Сообщение для товара 2</p>
        <button class="close-notification">Закрыть</button>
    </div>
    <img class="catalog__img" src="http://surl.li/mdsxm" alt="img">
    <div class="catalog__price">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
        <p class="catalog-price">1000$</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Сделал пример карточек с кнопкой по клику на которую появляеться модальное окно карточки, а также в модальном окне добавил кнопку зкрытия